# Selectively mute character where language is a barrier

Tags: fiction, technique, dialogue, fantasy

I have a mc that speaks only mandarin and is taken in by pirates that are mostly English speakers. He didn't speak much before being taken by them. So how would I write a character that is basically mute and doesn't understand what is being said to him?

Comment: You imagine what the experience would be like for _him_! For example, he would have to guess from the pirates' expressions, tone of voice etc. what they might be saying.

Comment: Michael Crichton's *Eaters of the Dead* (the movie *The 13th Warrior*) has an Arab MC who is rescued by Vikings and can't understand their language.